# wasysym not compatible with bm

Tags: wasysym

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontset=windows]{ctexart}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,wasysym}
\usepackage{autobreak}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso,frak=euler,bb=ams]{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{JetBrains Mono}

\begin{document}
\[
\bm{\Phi} % Or any capital Greek letters
\]
\end{document}
```

It will give a warning:

`` Font shape `U/wasy/b/n' in size <5> not available(Font) Font shape `U/wasy/m/n' tried instead ``

I use `wasysym` for astronomical symbols so I cannot delete it. How can I get rid of the warning?

Comment: Just a rough answer, just try with include the package `type1cm`, or `anysize`

Comment: Sorry, does not work for me. @MadyYuvi

Answer (score 2):

The warning is annoying, but harmless.

On the other hand, you can renew the font definitions for `wasy` taking into account that it is nowadays available as a Type1 font. Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{wasy}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasy}{m}{n}{
     <-5.5> wasy5
  <5.5-6.5> wasy6
  <6.5-7.5> wasy7
  <7.5-8.5> wasy8
  <8.5-9.5> wasy9
     <9.5-> wasy10
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasy}{b}{n}{
 <-10> ssub * wasy/m/n
 <10-> wasyb10
 }{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasy}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * wasy/b/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasy}{m}{sl}{ <-> wasysl10 }{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{wasy}{m}{it}{ <-> ssub * wasy/m/sl }{}
```

and the warnings will disappear. By the way, it was a precise choice by the font developer to issue those warnings, because in `uwasy.fd` we find `sub` instead of `ssub` (silent substitution).

Answer (score 1):

Use `\varPhi` instead of `\Phi` (and also other capital Greek letters).